# Error MySQL CentOS - Starting MySQLCouldn't find MySQL server

Tags: mysql, centos

I can not make any operation in mysql:

```
root@server2 [~]# /etc/init.d/mysql status
MySQL is not running, but lock file (/var/lock/subsys/mysql[FAILED]
root@server2 [~]# /etc/init.d/mysql restart
MySQL server PID file could not be found!                  [FAILED]
/etc/init.d/mysql: line 301: cd: /usr/local/mysql: No such file or directory
Starting MySQLCouldn't find MySQL server (/usr/local/mysql/[FAILED]ld_safe)
root@server2 [~]# /etc/init.d/mysql stop
MySQL server PID file could not be found!                  [FAILED]
root@server2 [~]# /etc/init.d/mysql start
/etc/init.d/mysql: line 301: cd: /usr/local/mysql: No such file or directory
Starting MySQLCouldn't find MySQL server (/usr/local/mysql/[FAILED]ld_safe)
root@server2 [~]# mysql -u root
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (111)
```

My file /etc/my.cnf:

```
root@server2 [~]# cat /etc/my.cnf
[mysqld]
user = mysql
basedir = /usr/local/mysql
skip-external-locking
key_buffer = 384M
max_allowed_packet=268435456
max_connections = 500
max_user_connections = 35
wait_timeout=40
connect_timeout=10
table_cache = 512
sort_buffer_size = 2M
read_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 8M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
thread_cache_size = 8
query_cache_size = 32M
thread_concurrency = 8
server-id       = 1
skip-innodb

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 256M
sort_buffer_size = 256M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

Searching in some posts, I found that some program may be holding mysql. Follow the command checked:

```
root@server2 [~]# lsof | grep mysql
tailwatch 20718      root  mem       REG        3,5    206553    8922204 /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/perl/514/lib/perl5/cpanel_lib/i386-linux-64int/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.so
```

yum info mysql-server

```
root@server2 [~]# yum info mysql-server
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.aol.com
 * extras: centos.chi.host-engine.com
 * updates: mirror.lug.udel.edu
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
Error: No matching Packages to list
```

Other information ..

- There is no process running mysql.
- CentOS release 5.10 (Final)
- I already deleted files with extension .err and tried again. But it did not work.
- When I try to start mysql in safe mode, apparently there is no error. But still does not work and any subsequent operation does not work.

Comment: This question would be better asked on **dba.stackexchange.com** or **serverfault.com**.

Comment: Question migrated: http://serverfault.com/questions/625046/error-mysql-centos-starting-mysqlcouldnt-find-mysql-server?noredirect=1#comment749647_625046